# Mozpay hitting postbackURL 6 times

Tags: mozilla, firefox-os

I have set up mozpay in my app. When I send the signed jwt with the post-back URL to the app, and then the app uses it with mozpay, during simulation, the post-back URL gets hit 6 times. I wanted to know if that's intended. If so i can work around it, but if its not intended i would rather fix that problem.

Is it possible that the 6 post-backs only occur during simulation?

Also is this any different in the charge-back URL?

Is there a setting that I can set in the signed jwt to change this?

If there is some documentation on this, I haven't been able to find it, and I would greatly appreciate a link.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Monetization/In-app_payments_section/mozPay_iap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an answer here, but I dont see it anymore. The answer was fairly correct.

We were sending back "webpay: {transactionID}" what we didnt realize is that {transactionID} includes the text "webpay:" So all we had to do was send back "{transactionID}" instead.

I would set as the answer the person who posted, but i no longer see the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is expected behavior. Since your postback URL was not responding correctly, Mozilla's server retried the post 5 additional times before giving up. As you mention, when you fixed the transaction response you no longer saw so many requests.